# Emit signals from QgraphicsItem

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, signals-slots, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

Hi this is a follow on question from my earlier query **Getting events from Context Menu action on QGraphicsItems**
I am now trying to emit a signal from myQgraphicsItem, the goal being when a user right clicks
and selects action1 the notifyaction1 function will tell the scene to do something (Add more items to the graphicsitem that sent the signal)
After doing some research i find that the QgraphicsItem cannot emit, see ***Stack Overflow:
Events and signals in Qt's QGraphicsItem: How is this *supposed* to work?***

So I added a signaling_object (QObject) to my class, but I am not sure how to send/receive the signal so that the parent scene can get the notification of the user's action.

```
class Node(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
Type = QtGui.QGraphicsItem.UserType + 1

def __init__(self, Parent=None):
    super(Node, self).__init__()


    self.edgeList = []
    self.newPos = QtCore.QPointF()

    self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
    self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
    self.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.DeviceCoordinateCache)
    self.setZValue(1)
    self.signaling_object=QtCore.QObject()

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
def notifyaction(self):
    #print "action1"
    message="action1"

    QtCore.QObject.emit(self.signaling_object,QtCore.SIGNAL('action_update(QString)'),str(message))
    print self.signaling_object.signalsBlocked()
    child_items=self.childItems()
    for item in child_items:
        #print item
        item.hide()
    self.hide()


def contextMenuEvent(self, contextEvent):
    object_cntext_Menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    object_cntext_Menu.addAction("action1")        
    object_cntext_Menu.addAction("action2", self.notifyaction)
    object_cntext_Menu.addAction("action3")
    position=QtGui.QCursor.pos() 
    object_cntext_Menu.exec_(position)
```

Is there anyway to send notifcations to other qt objects from a qgraphicsItem's context menu. I am using PyQt/Python on windows
Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want signal/slot support for graphics items, you could use [QGraphicsObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsobject.html) instead of `QGraphicsItem`. This would allow you to emit customs signals, like this:

```
class Node(QtGui.QGraphicsObject):
    customSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    ...

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def notifyaction(self):
        message = 'action1'
        self.customSignal.emit(message)
```

To receive these custom signals, just connect an appropriate handler:

```
 item.customSignal.connect(scene.handleCustomSignal)
```

However, it may be simpler to avoid signals altogether and just call the scene directly. Every graphics item can access the scene its been added to via its [scene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#scene) method. So you could just do something as simple as this:

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def notifyaction(self):
        message = 'action1'
        scene = self.scene()
        if scene is not None:
            scene.handleItemAction(self, message)
```

And doing things this way means you don't have to connect up signals for every graphics item that is created.

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro, I used you're second suggestion in avoiding signals all together and doing scene.handleItemAction. Seems quite obvious when you mention it, but I was so stuck with the idea of slots/signals. Thank you very much